# VueJS 2.0: Programmatic Navigation not working

Tags: navigation, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm facing a weird problem with the Programmatic Navigation of VueJS 2.0 router because I cannot receive as props the params I sent from X component to Y.

I have this route in my routes.js

```
{
  path: '/email-verification',
  name: 'email-verification',
  component: EmailVerification,
  props: true,
},
```

So after I perform the form submission in X I have to navigate to the Y component and to do that I have the following code:

```
router.push({ path: 'email-verification', params: { email: this.email } });
```

The navigation works but I'm not receiving the **email** param in the Y component.

I'm trying to get the **props** using this:

```
export default {
  name: 'login',
  props: ['email'],
}
```

But when I try to access to the email prop, is always **undefined**

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As I found in the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html), you should only use "props" instead of "params"

There is a line

```
props: { default: true, sidebar: false }
```

Comment: That documentation is to set static props.

Answer (score 0):

When you dinamically define your route, you have to put its "name" instead its "path", so your sentence should have been:

router.push({ **name**: 'email-verification', params: { email: this.email } });